# Put more than one line with morris.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, morris.js

I am trying to make a graph with morris.js and I need to represent 2 lines in a graph, how can I do it?

I have 2 sets of data in one array, but I can't see any line, if I put `todos[0]`, I can see the first line and with `todos[1]` the second, but I want to see both of them. I want to put more than 2 lines, and I will use this with an ajax function, but now I need to see 2 lines, what should I do? I don't know how to see both lines.

```js
var datos = [
  { year: 2008, value: 20 },
  { year: 2009, value: 10 },
  { year: 2010, value: 5 },
  { year: 2011, value: 5 },
  { year: 2012, value: 20 }
];

var total = [];
var cont = 0;

while (cont < 100) {
  var nuevo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6000) * cont;
  var nuevoYear = 2012 + cont

  //console.log(nuevoYear);
  datos.push({
    year: nuevoYear,
    value: String(nuevo),
  });

  cont++;
}

total.push(datos);

var datos2 = [
  { year: 2008, value: 120 },
  { year: 2009, value: 110 },
  { year: 2010, value: 51 },
  { year: 2011, value: 51 },
  { year: 2012, value: 201 }
];

var cont2 = 0;
while (cont2 < 100) {
  var nuevo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6000) * cont2;
  var nuevoYear = 2012 + cont2

  //console.log(nuevoYear);
  datos2.push({
    year: nuevoYear,
    value: String(nuevo),
  });

  cont2++;
}

total.push(datos2);
//console.log([total]);

new Morris.Line({
  // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
  element: 'myfirstchart',
  // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to
  // a point on the chart.
  data: total[0],
  // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
  xkey: 'year',
  // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
  ykeys: ['value'],
  // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over
  // the chart.
  labels: ['Value']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container todo my-5">
  <div class="contDiv">
    <div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your values in the same object for each year. Don't forget to set the `parseTime` to `false` to prevent Morris from interpreting dates.

Please try the following snippet:

```js
var datos = [
    { year: 2008, v1: 20, v2: 120 },
    { year: 2009, v1: 10, v2: 110 },
    { year: 2010, v1: 5, v2: 51 },
    { year: 2011, v1: 5, v2: 51 },
    { year: 2012, v1: 20, v2: 201 }
];

var cont = 0;

while (cont < 100) {
    var nuevo1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6000) * cont;
    var nuevo2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6000) * cont;
    var nuevoYear = 2012 + cont

    datos.push({
        year: nuevoYear,
        v1: String(nuevo1),
        v2: String(nuevo2),
    });

    cont++;
}

new Morris.Line({
    element: 'myfirstchart',
    data: datos,
    xkey: 'year',
    ykeys: ['v1', 'v2'],
    labels: ['Value 1', 'Value 2'],
    parseTime: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
    <div id="myfirstchart"></div>
</div>
```

New version, based on comments:

```js
var startYear = 2008;
var years = 5;

var data = [];
var labels = [];
var ykeys = [];

for (var i = startYear; i < startYear + years; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    obj["year"] = i;

    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        obj["v" + (j + 1)] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6000) * (j + 1);

        if (i == startYear) {
            labels.push("Value " + (j + 1));
            ykeys.push("v" + (j + 1));
        }
    }

    data.push(obj);
}

new Morris.Line({
    element: 'myfirstchart',
    data: data,
    xkey: 'year',
    ykeys: ykeys,
    labels: labels,
    parseTime: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
    <div id="myfirstchart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: and how could I do all of this inside a for loop? since it would not have v1 and v2 but it would be n times v_i, for example doing this in a loop where i = 0, i <4

Comment: Construct your objects dynamically with `var obj = {}; obj[year] = year; obj["v_" + i] = value;` and then push your object to your data array.

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand you, i can add the values fot the object but in yKeys, i have tu put the values too, can you give me an example pls?

Comment: Yes, you need to construct the ykeys and labels dynamically too. Sorry, I need to go, I'll try to do an example tomorrow.

Comment: I dont know how to do this with a for loop, can you send me the example pls?? i cant create v_i values in my loop and i dont know what should i do, thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want? What exactly do want with your years and values?

Comment: for example, value 1.4 and year 2001, i will have 4 aarrays with 50 values and 50 year for each array

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me. Maybe if you put some context can I understand better.

Comment: okey, i have this = [  [1,2], [6,3], [1,6] ]
and i want to have this => [1,6,1] and other array with [2,3,6], what can i do?? i want to group all the values in one array

Comment: I've done a new version, I hope it's what you're looking for.